Counting L2 cache misses and cache accesses with PAPI_L2_TCM and PAPI_L2_TCA gives cache misses greater than cache accesses leading to miss ratio > 1
I am trying to use the PAPI library (v7.1) to count cache misses, cache accesses and get the miss ratio for the L2 cache. My EventSet comprises the total number of cycles (PAPI_TOT_CYC), total cache misses at the L2 level (PAPI_L2_TCM) and total cache accesses at the L2 level (PAPI_L2_TCA).
    int numEvents = 3;

    long long values[3];

    int EventCode[3] = {PAPI_TOT_CYC,PAPI_L2_TCM,PAPI_L2_TCA};
    long long start_usec, end_usec;

    int EventSet = PAPI_NULL;
    int retval;

    /* Initialize the PAPI library*/
    retval = PAPI_library_init(PAPI_VER_CURRENT);
    if (retval != PAPI_VER_CURRENT)
        handle_error(retval);

    /* Create an EventSet */ 
    retval = PAPI_create_eventset(&EventSet);
    if (retval != PAPI_OK)
        handle_error(retval);

    /* Add clock cycles, cache accesses, cache misses (EventCode) to our EventSet */
    retval = PAPI_add_events(EventSet, EventCode, numEvents);
    if(retval != PAPI_OK)
        handle_error(retval);

    /* Start counting */
    retval = PAPI_start(EventSet);
    if(retval != PAPI_OK)
        handle_error(retval);

    fillSparseMatrix(nX,nY,nZ,Ellpack);

    retval = PAPI_read(EventSet, values);

    if(retval != PAPI_OK)
        handle_error(retval);

    std::cout << "AFTER ELLPACK FILL:\n";
    std::cout<<"Clock cycles : "<<values[0]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"L2 misses : "<<values[1]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"L2 accesses : "<<values[2]<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"L2 cache miss ratio : "<< (double)values[1]/values[2] <<std::endl;

The main problem I am running into is that I am getting L2 misses greater than L2 accesses and so the miss ratio being printed is greater than 1.
I tried running a different part of the application - a jacobian solver with the same code as above, just a different function call to solve the Jacobian and that gave a miss ratio within 1:
    /* Initialize the PAPI library*/
    retval = PAPI_library_init(PAPI_VER_CURRENT);
    if (retval != PAPI_VER_CURRENT)
        handle_error(retval);

    /* Create an EventSet */ 
    retval = PAPI_create_eventset(&EventSet);
    if (retval != PAPI_OK)
        handle_error(retval);

    // /* Add clock cycles, cache accesses, cache misses (EventCode) to our EventSet */
    retval = PAPI_add_events(EventSet, EventCode, numEvents);
    if(retval != PAPI_OK)
        handle_error(retval);

    // // /* Start counting */
    retval = PAPI_start(EventSet);
    if(retval != PAPI_OK)
        handle_error(retval);

    // Call serial Function
    int output_id = serialLaplacePDEJacobiSolver(U, U2, num_rows, num_cols, max_iters, err_thres);

    retval = PAPI_read(EventSet, values);
    if(retval != PAPI_OK)
        handle_error(retval);

    retval = PAPI_stop(EventSet, values);
    if(retval != PAPI_OK)
        handle_error(retval);

    cout<<"Clock cycles: "<<values[0]<<endl;
    cout<<"L2 misses: "<<values[1]<<endl;
    cout<<"L2 accesses: "<<values[2]<<endl;
    cout<<"L2 miss/access ratio: "<<(double)values[1]/values[2]<<endl;

However I need cache misses metrics for the function that I have implemented above. I am unsure of what is causing the performance counter to add calls and incur greater number of cache misses than accesses. Both the functions are implemented in different classes.
